# "ARP -a" Command Explanation

Tags: cmd, packet-sniffers, arp

I have tried to execute the `ARP -a` command in windows. I knew that it is used for mapping IP with MAC addresses.

[image: Check the Image]

I know the first part there but what about the other two-block? Why is at last there 0x10 and 0x16?

Comment: Maybe VPN adapter or alike? Check `netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces` and/or `netsh wlan show interfaces` or `powershell -c  Get-NetAdapter`,

Comment: What about 0xc , 0x10, 0x16 ? I know they are hexadecimal values but what is their use or what is the purpose ?

Comment: Each of those numbers specifies the network adapter interface index number. It's a property of a NIC, see [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_addresses_lh). However, _the adapter index values specified in the `IfIndex` and `Ipv6IfIndex` members may change when an adapter is disabled and then enabled, or under other circumstances, and should not be considered persistent._